# What considerations to make before applying an LSTM on unseen data

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I had some text data on which I wanted to train a classifier - for this I used an LSTM.
I tokenized and vectorized my text data, so that legible text like 'The quick brown fox...' was turned into padded sequences '[1,0,0,25,...]' etc.

A model has been successfully trained. Now, I need to apply this model to unseen text data (not part of train or test sets).

I was initially considering removing all words from unseen data that are not present in trained/tested data. But this too does not look like a solution, as upon tokenizing the unseen text data, the words present in trained data may be mapped to new numbers in the unseen data.

So,

- fox in trained data may be mapped to 20
- fox in unseen data may be mapped to 70

My question, then, is: How can I apply an LSTM model on new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't like the solution where unseen data would have a new number. Because it will confuse your model...

I see two solutions:

- fit a tokenizer on all words from the train and test datasets. Just combine these files for making tokenization only.
- Use a large text dataset (f.e. Wikipedia) for fitting your tokenizer, in that case you are most likely to have all words.

Comment: thanks for your contribution. I think the 2nd solution could work. But for the 1st, problem seems to remain unresolved. Because my problem will be with unseen data (which is hard to collect/unavailable at time of training). So I have a tokenizer on train and test sets, but it isn't based on unseen set. Is there anyway to ensure each word maps to the same number?

Comment: Sure, every tokenizer has a dictionary, and you able to check the word by a key (number) or vice versa. F.i. using vocabulary_ method you have access to all word number pair. 
In order to help you more, I need to know which tokenizer you are using...

Comment: for keras you have attributes, check the bottom: https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/